# Xcode linking to library to hard-coded derived data path on another machine

Tags: xcode, hyperlink, workspace

In my Xcode App workspace, we have a library A, and another library B that the lib A depends on. The iOS app uses lib A and B.

Using the "Link binary with libraries" section, i can add all the dependencies in, but they are pointing to derived data folders.

In source control, I can see the hardcoded derived data path in the project, so my question is how does this work on another machine, and is there a better way to link libraries in a workspace using just project references?